# How I can convert a list of integers to an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I converted an image to a list of integers.
E.g.
[226, 137, 125, 226, 137, 125, 223, 137, 133, 223, 136, 128, 226, 138, 120, 226, 129, 116, 228, 138, 123, 227, 134, 124, 227, 140, 127, 225, 136, 119, 228, 135, 126, 225, 134, 121, 223, 130, 108, 226, 139, 119, 223, 135, 120, 221, 129, 114, 221, 134, 108, 221, 131, 113, 222, 138, 121, 222, 139, 114, 223, 127, 109, 223, 132, 105, 224, 129, 102, 221, 134, 109, 218, 131, 110, 221, 133, 113, 223, 130, 108, 225, 125, 98, 221, 130, 121, 221, 129, 111, 220, 127, 121, 223, 131, 109, 225, 127, 103, 223]
How I can reverse this process and recover my image. I used PIL library and python 3.6.

Comment: Where are the dimensions of the image please?

Comment: I used lena.png RGB image & its dimensions are 512*512

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PIL and numPy. Try the code as given below.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


pixels =[226, 137, 125, 226, 137, 125, 223, 137, 133, 223, 136, 128, 226, 138, 120, 226, 129, 116, 228, 138, 123, 227, 134, 124, 227, 140, 127, 225, 136, 119, 228, 135, 126, 225, 134, 121, 223, 130, 108, 226, 139, 119, 223, 135, 120, 221, 129, 114, 221, 134, 108, 221, 131, 113, 222, 138, 121, 222, 139, 114, 223, 127, 109, 223, 132, 105, 224, 129, 102, 221, 134, 109, 218, 131, 110, 221, 133, 113, 223, 130, 108, 225, 125, 98, 221, 130, 121, 221, 129, 111, 220, 127, 121, 223, 131, 109, 225, 127, 103, 223] 

# Convert the pixels into an array using numpy
array = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)

# Use PIL to create an image from the new array of pixels
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
new_image.save('new.png')
```

Or

```
image_out = Image.new(image.mode,image.size)
image_out.putdata(pixels)


image_out.save('test_out.png')
```

Comment: The first one works when you have a list of Tuples with RGB values.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to do this
 {
newpixels = tuple(list3)
array = np.array(newpixels, dtype=np.uint8)

# Use PIL to create an image from the new array of pixels
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
new_image.save('new.png') 
}
but this also gave me the next error
{
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\new.py", line 54, in <module>
    new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2529, in fromarray
    size = shape[1], shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
} 
hint: list3 is the list of integers

Comment: No he means tuples of Red Green and Blue color values. Each pixel would be represented as a set of 3 8 bit(usually 8 hu can be more or less) numbers that represent how much red green or blue there is. So you'd want to club you numbers into tuples of 3 and take the list of these tuples and write that as the image

Comment: what is image there in (image.mode,image.size)

Comment: @BerylAmend, I am sorry, a part of code is missing. It was supposed to be an image object. You can instead do this `Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (1280, 720))`

Comment: @Irfanuddin tnx dude

Answer (score 0):

calling list on bytes gives you a list of integers.

```
some_bytes = b'\xbe\xbf\xc0'

list(some_bytes)

[190, 191, 192]
```

calling bytes on a list of integers gives you bytes.

```
bytes([190,191,192])

b'\xbe\xbf\xc0'
```

read an image into a list of integers:

```
>>>> with open("acme.png","rb") as ifile:
....     a_list= list(ifile.read())
....
```

write that list of integers to a new image file

```
>>>> with open("acme2.png","wb+") as ofile:
....     ofile.write(bytes(a_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

````
```

std::vector<unsigned char> buffer, buffer1;

cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer);

cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer1);

Poco::JSON::Object obj;

obj.set("photo1", buffer);

obj.set("photo2", buffer1);

std::stringstream ss;

obj.stringify(ss);

std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl // From here i getting image data as array
````

```
import cv2 as cv

import numpy as np

import cv2

# data["photo1"] string from C++ I Created and With the Python i converted back to image

# read image as an numpy array

image = np.asarray(bytearray(data["photo1"]), dtype="uint8")
    
# use imdecode function

new_image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv.imshow("image",new_image)

cv.waitKey(0)
```